# Css or javascript scroll transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have two divs with:

```
width:100%; height:100%
```

so my whole document has an height of 200%;
both div`s have an link to each other,

now when i click on the link, i want that the site smoothly slides to the other div,

I know how this would work in jquery , for example with .scrollto, but my client wants an app wihout frameworks. Only javascricpt and css!

I tried to achive it with translateY, but it didnt worked!

Here is an exemplary code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hSU7R/

### The HTML

```
<div class="full" id="one">
   <span style="width:100%; background-color:blue">
   <a href="#two" >Scroll to 2</a>
   </span>    
</div>


<div class="full" id="two">
    <span style="width:100%; background-color:blue">
    <a href="#one" >Scroll to 1</a></span>
</div>
```

### The CSS

```
html,body { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}

.full {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;}

#one {background-color:green}
#two {background-color:red}
```

Comment: A basic presentation of the code would be wellcome into your post too...

Comment: This link might help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp

Comment: CSS3 allowed or you need to support IE8 and below?

Comment: @Aaron Please _don't_ link to w3Schools, only what can be adapted there is a bad practice and non-working code : (.

Comment: @Teemu http://jsfiddle.net/hSU7R/  is the basic presentation!

Comment: @Fabrício Matté only has to work in webkit browser! Thanks

Comment: @Aaron Thanks man! YOu showed me the right direction!! Now i found that code http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/1/

Comment: @EmSta Yes it is, but thinking about future visitors, it's always better to include the code to the post too, who knows when jsFiddle goes down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [A fork of your jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/hSU7R/17/)

There has to be a smarter way to do this, but that's why we have jQuery right? My basic idea was to grab each anchor and turn off the default click response. Then, replace it with one that starts a `setInterval` chain. Each time the interval transpires, the window will incrementally scroll based on a frame rate and an estimated total run time. The actual run-time seems to take longer than the input time, but it at least gives you a way to get started.

What is the main disadvantage to using jQuery? I would think you'd get better performance from their implementation, since the jQuery people work on this stuff all the time.

Comment: Finally i achieved the same with javascript as you can see here:

Comment: Finally i achieved the same with javascript as you can see here:http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/1/                                                                 The thing is that at the moment iam designing an app with phonegap, when i include jquery the app has long loading times, so that i decided only to use javascript. Now i have another problem i want to add another link in the middle of the page. The viewport should scroll to this link, and stop when the link is at the bottom of the page. I hope somebody understands what i mean, heres a demo! http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/8/ Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the scroll ([speed, direction, position(?)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)) behavior with css.

CSS3 transitions enables to specify the way an element will go from a state to another while `scroling` is not an `element`. But you can position the `body`.

There is '[scroll-snap-points](http://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-snap-points)' wich might relate.

> A CSS technique that allows customizable scrolling experiences like
>   pagination of carousels by setting defined snap points.

[jsfiddled example](https://jsfiddle.net/40zkgjfn/)

CSS

```
.gallery {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(1000px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1000px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img alt="" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/1.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/2.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/3.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/4.jpg">
</div>
```